# What is a "component function" of a matrix that is a linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

The matrix is:
$$
\pmatrix{
1&2\\
3&4}
$$
and this matrix is an $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ linear map. I am asked to explicitly write the component functions of $A$. What does "component functions" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably asking for

$$f_1(x,y)=x+2y\\
f_2(x,y)= 3x+4y$$